# How can i switch params values on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to switch params[:starts_at] and params[:ends_at] if the user passes an 'end_at' time before the 'start_at'

here's what i did but i don't think it's working

```
def create
    if params[:starts_at] > params[:ends_at]
      params[:starts_at],params[:ends_at] = params[:ends_at],params[:starts_at]
    end
    if !booking.save
      report_sentry_errors(booking)
      render json: booking.errors.messages, status: :unprocessable_entity
    else
      render 'show', status: :created
    end
end
```

request exapmle :

```
starts_at:  "2022-10-09T10:30:00.000Z"
ends_at:    "2022-10-09T09:00:00.000Z"
```

Comment: "but i don't think it's working" - why do you think that?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i've made some tests and it returns error on the tests, this means that the condition `if params[:starts_at] > params[:ends_at]` is not valid and it returns false

Comment: Well, maybe there's a bug in your tests (setup or checks). The code, as shown, will work.

Comment: "...it returns error on the tests,..."requires elaboration. If you are referring to an exception being raised you need to state the exception and give the line of code in which it was raised. This is general advice as an exception message often pinpoints the cause of the error.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I've found the solution it was not the from the tests as sergio-tulentsev said

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I posted a solution that worked for me without changing my tests

Comment: @MagicPants In both your updated question code and this answer, `booking` is undefined. Its declaration got lost during removing irrelevant code, I think. And that's where the problem was, I bet. You were initializing a booking before changing params.

Answer (score 0):

The logic was pretty correct, I had to change the `params` with the `booking`

```
def create

     if booking.starts_at > booking.ends_at
       booking.starts_at,booking.ends_at = booking.ends_at,booking.starts_at
     end

    if !booking.save
      report_sentry_errors(booking)
      render json: booking.errors.messages, status: :unprocessable_entity
    else
      render 'show', status: :created
    end
end
```